# C2252 error when building GLUI with VS2017?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017, glut, glui

I downloaded GLUI 2.36 and set out to build the Visual Studio project in VS 2017, Windows 10. After getting the GLUT libraries correctly installed, I still get the following compile-time errors:

```
1>glui.cpp
1>c:\install\glui-2.36\glui-2.36\src\include\gl\glui.h(1718): error C2252: an explicit instantiation of a template can only occur at namespace scope
```

And likewise on most of the source files.

What is the best resolution for this? Or can I download a more up-to-date version somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

2.36 is from [2007](https://github.com/libglui/glui/releases/tag/2.36).  2.37 (the latest release) was tagged in [2015](https://github.com/libglui/glui/releases/tag/2.37).

Your issue sounds like it was [fixed in 2015](https://github.com/libglui/glui/commit/85b8038d9dbe415b327480d6bffd008a0e79c382), and made it into 2.37:

> **fix MSVC problem with template class instantiation**
>
> - error C2252 informs that the microsoft compiler wants template    classes to be instantiated at namespace scope